# canvas not updated real-time by background thread

Tags: wpf, canvas, background, rendering

In .NET4.0 WPF, I want to display a drawingPath on a canvas using a background thread. The following ConsumerJob is correctly running in the background and polling a queue of points to draw. I use a Dispatcher to modify the canvas on the main thread and it gets correctly rendered. However, I would expect this code to display each segment one at a time as and when each children.add gets invoked(like an animation). What happens is that the whole display gets rendered at once and not one segment at a time. How should I modify the code to render the display as the children get added one at a time?

```
public void ConsumerJob()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            PointsD pt = (PointsD)queue.Consume();
            displayQueue.Enqueue(pt);

            pt = Scale(pt);

            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                (ThreadStart)delegate()
                {
                    Path drawingPath = new Path();
                    StreamGeometry streamingGeometry = new StreamGeometry();
                    drawingPath.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                    drawingPath.StrokeThickness = 0.5;

                    using (StreamGeometryContext ctx = streamingGeometry.Open())
                    {
                            ctx.BeginFigure(new Point(pt.x0, pt.y0), false, false);
                            ctx.LineTo(new Point(pt.x1, pt.y1), true, false);
                    }

                    streamingGeometry.Freeze();
                    drawingPath.Data = streamingGeometry;

                    this.Children.Add(drawingPath);

                }
                );

        }
```

Comment: Other option could have been to use a `BackgroundWorker`, it provides 3 events such as DoWork() (with only the delegate code above), ProgressNotified() (adding the child in canvas) and  WorkCompleted() (to schedule the next bit RunAsync() of the bgworker), which gives it a feel that it is an eternally working thread that notifies UI thread synchronously to add new bits to the canvas as an animation.

Answer (score 1):

`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` is asynchronous, have you tried its synchronous counterpart `Invoke`?

That should at least enforce that all queued delegates are executed in the right order, not sure about the timing though.

You might also want to try a higher DispatcherPriority in addition to that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed BeginInvoke to Invoke and it is now working perfectly. The path gets displayed real-time. I am still surprised about that as you say, not clear why this affects the timing. Useful if anyone has clues.

Comment: @ChristopheBraun: Well, BeginInvoke returns immediately after queuing the delegate, so in all likelihood all updates get queued and executed in one cycle, leaving you with a jump. Invoke waits for the delegate being executed. Also see the [threading model reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx), it has some more info on how that queue works.